# No signature of method: .android() is applicable for argument types. Exception in build.gradle (app)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_h12dou32x8mktsbcdinr8fpc.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_h12dou32x8mktsbcdinr8fpc$_run_closure1) values: [build_h12dou32x8mktsbcdinr8fpc$_run_closure1@1630dea1]

Comment: Clean your project
Generate signed yours bundle/.apk file
Uncheck the "Remember password"
Manually put your password at "Key store password" and "Key password"
Click Next and you Done!.

Answer (score 44):

Best way to deal with this is going in the `android { ... }` block and start commenting out different methods/blocks until the configuration moves past the `.android()` error and you'll know which block is causing it. In my case it was a deprecated method in the `buildTypes { ... }` block.

Comment: I got help through this technique, thanks

Comment: I solved it also using this. In my case it was also useProguard inside the buildTypes, deleted that and it worked

Comment: That was my problem too (buildTypes)

Comment: I had following block which is the culprit:

    publishing {
        singleVariant("release")
    }

If I comment this then build is generating successfully!

Answer (score 30):

I recently had similar trouble. I had to rerun the project with a "build.gradle" file from another project that didn't have any issues. Then I narrowed the issue down to `useProguard true`. The issue disappeared after I commented out `useProguard true` as shown below:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        //useProguard true  <-- remove this line
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue when migrating to the AGP 7.0 when moving from `aaptOptions` to `androidResources`.

For me it was enough to replace

```
androidResources {
   noCompress '...'
}
```

with

```
aaptOptions {
   noCompress '...'
}
```

Comment: Back thats a way back right? It is recommended to upgraded from aapt to android resources

Comment: Any other possibility of this error? I don't have 'androidResources' in my build.gradle

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this error by removing 'useProguard' from app/build.gradle like so:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true

            // useProguard true <-- removed this
            proguardFiles(
                    getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
```

I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue when migrating to the `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'`

I removed the code:

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [fragmentArgsLogWarnings: 'false']
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
```

here is desc about how to add it again for kapt
https://github.com/sockeqwe/fragmentargs#annotation-processor-options

Answer (score 9):

There's no unique answer for this, except that it's a syntax typo inside `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 8):

`kotlinOptions` lambda caused error in my case.

```
android {
...
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
...
}
```

When I removed it - everything start to work back again.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, there was an unwanted character(a semicolon) in build.gradle(app)

I deleted that and rebuiled the project

problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

I was using -
(in build.gradle)
"versionCode" as RN-2 (* as i was developing in React Native)
then i tried "versionCode" as 3.1 but that also was throwing error
then i used -
`versionCode 4`

and this time the BUILD was SUCCESSFUL

**my learning* -> versionCode should be integer**

Comment: you really helped me. I had the same issue. in my gradle versionCode was 1.0 that's why I ran into trouble. I changed it to 1. now I have no issue :)

Answer (score 6):

The error can have many origins. One most frequent is due to **syntax typo inside build.gradle** file and there's no easy way to spot it.

My suggestion. **Copy the code from a working build.grade file on another project and replace the part that is throwing the error.**

Answer (score 5):

For me, when I was downgrading the GradleVersion and some dependencie, I had to remove this line from *build.gradle (:app)*

```
android {
...
    namespace 'com.yourpackagename' <-- delete this line
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I removed the `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'` plugin from build.gradle(:app).

It was fixed by also removing

```
    android {
        ...
        androidExtensions {
            experimental = true
        }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to comment all elements in `android {}` section, sync & build and then uncomment. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

remove

"useProguard true"

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            //useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.
There was a library in project having,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
```

in the build.gradle file of library.
I added the same,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
```

in build.gradle file of app.
It was causing this error.
I changed it back to,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

This solved my issue.

Comment: so at the end, app module will have `id 'com.android.application'`, and library module will have `id 'com.android.library'`? I still stuck with this problem

Answer (score 2):

I had this error `No signature of method: build_eux4i9fuz78eb5ojbn76y01n5.android() is applicable for argument types`

It was fixed by changing

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

to

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

I believe the error is the cause of version conflicts between kotlin plugin version and gradle version.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've commented `buildTools`

```
android {
    compileSdk 32
//    buildTools "32.1.0 rc1"
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new project and added dependencies, and this error occurred.

In my case the problem was `namespace` 'com.appName.packageName.app' line in `build.gradle` file. Deleting this helped me.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.mathtask.app' // Delete this line
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mathtask.app"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

An absolutely Ludicrous error being issued by Android Studio

Mind you this has been compiling absolutely fine in previous versions of AS and Gradle until I upgraded a couple of days ago.

I had accidentally in one of my modules typed a Capital letter (many months ago mind you) as follows ;

```
DefaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 30
}
```

After so many hours of searching and trying various things I just happened to spot it.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 30
}
```

The above resolved the issue.

`DefaultConfig` -> `defaultConfig`

Answer (score 1):

This error is a bit misleading.
A simple typo can cause this error

[image]

I just had the spelling of "multidexEnabled" wrong.

Comment: OMG...Finally fix my issue: A typo. The error description is so misleading!

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove All the dependencies related to **protobuf** .

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly no unique answer here. Every developer faced some issue unique to their own `gradle` file configuration. For me, it started to appear during a migration to `gradle-7.0`. However, It worked when I realised and fixed the missing plugin in `app-gradle`

Plugin that my file was missing

```
id 'kotlin-android'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plugins {
      id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
```

build.gradle add this plugin on app level Gradle then sync

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working with `productFlavors`, setting up a boolean property. I forgot to surround the boolean value with apostrophes.

So I changed this

```
productFlavors {
    normal {
        flavorDimension "access"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_ADMIN', false
    } 

    admin {
        flavorDimension "access"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_ADMIN', true
    }
}
```

to this

```
productFlavors {
    normal {
        flavorDimension "access"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_ADMIN', 'false'
    } 

    admin {
        flavorDimension "access"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_ADMIN', 'true'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this error by changing version code to less than 6. using 7 onwards will exist this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I defined flavorDimensions using kotlin style instead of groovy

```
flavorDimensions += listOf("api", "mode")
```

Fixed it this way

```
flavorDimensions += ["api", "mode"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i could fix it commenting the : MultiDexEnable value on android.defaultConfig

Answer (score 0):

For me, I changed build:gradle.7.1.2 to 4.1.0 and work very good

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do that:

```
buildTypes {
    release {

        /**
         * Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
         * your project's release build type.
         * */
        minifyEnabled true

        /**
         * Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
         * Android Gradle plugin.
         * */
        shrinkResources true

        /**
         * Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
         * the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
         * R8 configuration files.
         * */
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        /**
         * Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
         * your project's release build type.
         * */
        minifyEnabled true

        /**
         * Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
         * Android Gradle plugin.
         * */
        shrinkResources true

        /**
         * Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
         * the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
         * R8 configuration files.
         * */
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens during upgrading process of very old project and when some gradle file parts edited manually and there is a mismatch. It is very time consuming and sometimes very painful to find what is the exact problem as generated errors may not even correctly indicate the issue.

One complex solution is to create new project with exact same package name and then copy-paste working-logic part into that project. This is easier solution as when we create new project all gradle, sdk, dependecies automatically created.

It happened with my Flutter project upgrade and managed to solve the issue only this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this problem because of jackOptions.I solve this to remove bellow code from android:

```
jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
```

Comment: Hi Ali, where do I add this ?

Comment: Inside android you have to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was `storeFile` value. following work fine for me.

```
storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFileUpload'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFileUpload']) : null
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove this:

```
  proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have said, everybody has a different solution to this thanks to Gradle's crappy error messages. Or is it Groovy's fault? I'm not sure.

In my case, it was a bit esoteric, but I'll post it anyway, it might help someone.

I created a new Android project where the default skeleton Gradle files were using Android Gradle Plugin 7 and the new targetSdk (instead of targetSdkVersion), compileSdk (instead of compileSdkVersion) and minSdk (instead of minSdkVersion).

I changed AGP to 3.6.3 (for a weird reason, this is why this is probably no help to anyone) and got the error message because targetSdk/compileSdk/minSdk

Answer (score 0):

*Hi devs, just updated to AS-Dolphin and received this error while creating a new project.*

In my case the issue was **compileSdk, minSdk, targetSdk** all were missing **Version** keyword.

*When I added that the error was gone... **Woh!!!***

```
compileSdkVersion 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My error (or needed update) was that my `gradle-wrapper.properties` needs to be updated from an old `6.*` gradle version to `7.3.3` and my build.gradle to latest stable Kotlin and build tools version and also to update to latest target and compile version `33` :D. And voilá it worked like always...