# No signature of method: build_1upy3e43ytufmh38cj8qq5tbo.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1upy3e43ytufmh38cj8qq5tbo$_run_closure1)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an error while building gradle in build.gradle(app) and spent several hours finding solution :

No signature of method: build_1upy3e43ytufmh38cj8qq5tbo.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1upy3e43ytufmh38cj8qq5tbo$_run_closure1) values: [build_1upy3e43ytufmh38cj8qq5tbo$_run_closure1@6871bd16]

my build.gradle(app) file is:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['AndroidManifest.xml']
        }
    }


    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.code.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 646
        versionName "5.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    lint {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha02'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.5.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    //implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.HotBitmapGG:RingProgressBar:V1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.1.0'
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    // Declare the dependencies for the Dynamic Links and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links'
    implementation 'com.github.dimorinny:floating-text-button:0.0.4'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
    //implementation project(path: ':sinch-android-rtc-3.17.4')
    //implementation(name:'sinch-android-rtc' , version :'3.17.4' , ext:'aar')
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:7.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:7.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.8'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.github.Jay-Goo:RangeSeekBar:v3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.4.0'
    implementation 'me.bendik.simplerangeview:simplerangeview:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.iwgang:countdownview:2.1.6'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.4'
    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.1.1'
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:7.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.18.1'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.cloudrail:cloudrail-si-android:2.6.5'

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation "org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.4.0"

    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'

    

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Can anyone help me find solution?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67418660/no-signature-of-method-android-is-applicable-for-argument-types-exception-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution is removing:

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
lint {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```